# How to add a script that types in the password for my vps through applescript

Tags: terminal, applescript, ssh

I made a script recently and have turned it into an app, it basicly logs me into my vps via ssh but I don't know how to tell it how to type in my password for me, heres the code

```
 tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "ssh root@example.com"
end tell
```

Comment: Use passwordless authentication: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152

Comment: it didn't work, I probably messed up

Comment: @surferconor425 It's not that hard to fix, might be a better route to take. I also got it wrong the first few times but it is actually quite easy to get up and running.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is pretty bad. You should never have a password written in a file. 
But here is the solution you asked.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "ssh root@example.com"
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "yourPasswordHere"
        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
```